# How do I display exact number of Questions only

Tags: c#, vb.net

In `Question set` i am getting all questions with particular `(topicID,Marks)`.  I am displaying Question **randomly** for `totqsn` i.e. total number of questions to display say 10 questions ,I am storing Count for number of questions of particular marks(1,2,3,4) in this int variables `mark1Qsn,mark2Qsn,mark3Qsn,mark4Qsn` respectively ,
using below code i am able to display Qustions from QuestionSet(say contains 34 qustions with (TopicID,marks)) for totqsn(say display 10 questions randomly from QuestionSet).My problem is
How can i display total 10 Question in which 3 questions of 1 mark,3 questions of 2mark,1 question of 3marks,3 questions of 4 marks i.e.
`totqsn(10 questions= 3 qsn_of_mark1 + 3 qsn_of_mark2 + 1 qsn_of_mark3 + 3 qsn_of_mark3)`

```
public partial class GroupExmStart : Form
{        
    DBHandling db = new DBHandling();

    string GrpID = "";
    string TopiID = "";
    int totQsn = 0;
    int mark1qsn = 0;
    int mark2Qsn = 0;
    int mark3Qsn = 0;
    int mark4Qsn = 0;
    int tik = 0;
    string QuestionSet = "";
    static Random _r = new Random();
    string[] randomQsn = null;
    string[] QAndA = null;
    public GroupExmStart(string GroupName, string DurationID)
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        totQsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[0]);    
        mark1qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[3]);//this variable contains number of question to be display of mark 1
        mark2Qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[4]);
        mark3Qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[5]);
        mark4Qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[6]); 

        QuestionSet = db.GetQuestions(TopiID, "1");
        QuestionSet = QuestionSet + db.GetQuestions(TopiID, "2");
        QuestionSet = QuestionSet + db.GetQuestions(TopiID, "3");
        QuestionSet = QuestionSet + db.GetQuestions(TopiID, "4");
        int z = Quiz(QuestionSet);

        foreach (string qa in QAndA.OrderBy(i => _random.Next()))
        {
            if (qa != null)
                if (qa.IndexOf('~') != -1)
                {
                    randomQsn[count] = qa;
                    count++;
                    if (count == totQsn)
                        break;
                }
        }

        int Quiz(string data)
        {
            string[] words = data.Split('$');
            randomQsn = new string[totQsn + 1];
            QAndA = new string[words.Length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < words.Length; i++)
            {
                QAndA[i] = words[i];
            }

            return 0;
        }
    }
}
```

GetQuestions method accessing from DBHandling class

```
public string GetQuestions(string TopicID, string Marks)
{
    string data = "";
    try
    {
        string sql = "select QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions where TopicID IN(" + TopicID + ") and Marks=" + Marks;
        cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, acccon);
        rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (rs.Read())
        {
            data = data + rs[0].ToString() + "~" + rs[1].ToString() + "~" + rs[2].ToString() + "~" + rs[3].ToString() + "~" + rs[4].ToString() + "~" + rs[5].ToString() + "~" + rs[6].ToString() + "~" + rs[7].ToString() + "$";
        }
    }
    catch (Exception err)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(err.Message.ToString());
    }
    return data;
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help

Comment: If you're asking how you do that and keep everything uniformly random, you should pick randomly from within "marks" and then union the results since you're trying to dictate the distribution of marks.

Comment: Can you please show it in my code I am not getting exactly how do i do it

Comment: Why arn't you defining classes to hold your questions? instead of concating then splitting strings? Does your `Quiz` method ever return something other than `0`? I'm just trying to understand your code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm trying to refactor your code a bit but it's very confusing.

Comment: The whole thing will work better if each question you retrieve can be its own object instance, put those into a collection of questions, then randomize the collection.

Comment: @Jay How can I hold Questions within class and than how do i access them randomly?

Comment: Take a look at Jeff's answer. He is spot on.

Comment: Thanks :). Guess I can get out of bed now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Completely untested and very messy but...

```
 public class Question
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Text { get; set; }

        public string Option1 { get; set; }
        public string Option2 { get; set; }
        public string Option3 { get; set; }
        public string Option4 { get; set; }

        public string AnswerOption { get; set; }
        public int Marks { get; set; }
    }

    public IEnumerable<Question> GetQuestions(string topicId, int marks)
    {
        string sql = "select QID,Question,Opt1,Opt2,Opt3,Opt4,AnsOp,Marks from Questions where TopicID IN(" +
                     topicId + ") and Marks=" + marks.ToString();
        var cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, new OleDbConnection(""));
        var rs = cmd.ExecuteReader();

        if (rs != null)
        {
            while (rs.Read())
            {
                yield return
                    new Question
                        {
                            Id = rs[0].ToString(),
                            Text = rs[1].ToString(),
                            Option1 = rs[2].ToString(),
                            Option2 = rs[3].ToString(),
                            Option3 = rs[4].ToString(),
                            Option4 = rs[5].ToString(),
                            AnswerOption = rs[6].ToString(),
                            Marks = marks
                        };
            }
        }
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        var totQsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[0]); // isn't this just the sum of everything else?
        var mark1qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[3]); //this variable contains number of question to be display of mark 1
        var mark2qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[4]);
        var mark3Qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[5]);
        var mark4Qsn = Convert.ToInt16(conf[6]);

        var mark1questionSet = GetQuestions(topicId, 1).ToList();
        var mark2questionSet = GetQuestions(topicId, 2).ToList();
        // etc

        var finalQuestions = new List<Question>();

        for (int i = 0; i < mark1qsn; i++)
        {
            var setIndex = _random.Next(mark1questionSet.Count);
            finalQuestions.Add(mark1questionSet[setIndex]);
            mark1questionSet.RemoveAt(setIndex);
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < mark2qsn; i++)
        {
            var setIndex = _random.Next(mark2questionSet.Count);
            finalQuestions.Add(mark2questionSet[setIndex]);
            mark2questionSet.RemoveAt(setIndex);
        }
        // etc - put this into a method or something
    }
```

Comment: You could create one "source" list and just `AddRange` with each query, the populating the `finalQuestions` list is trivial.

Comment: I agree there are better ways to organize it but doesn't that make it hard to pick questions of certain "mark", or am I missing something?

Comment: If you're trying to chat, I think you have to do an invite.

Comment: I dont know how to invite can you plesae send me an invite

Comment: Sorry, turns out I was wrong...are you still confused as to the solution?

Comment: yes ,because i have done it the way i have updated my question and i am confused now how do i use your solution into my code

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34811/discussion-between-durga-and-jeff)